# Retrieve cryptographic key knowing cyphertext and plaintext

Tags: encryption, symmetric

I was curious about cryptography so I started to learn about symmetric encryption.

From what I understand a symmetric encryption works as follow:

PlainText -> (Encrypt)K -> Cipher text -> (Decrypt)K -> PlainText

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the cryptographic key by knowing the **plain text**, the **cipher text** and the **encryption algorithm** used.

Comment: Did you do any reading before asking this question, e.g., on Wikipedia? Thomas has written up a nice answer to [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13274/the-difference-between-these-4-breaking-cipher-techniques).

Comment: @DrLecter: Great link, noted that answer for future use.