# How to defend AES against chosen-plaintext attack?

Tags: aes, chosen-plaintext-attack, known-plaintext-attack

I have a server which encrypts files with the same AES key. Users can upload a file and download its encrypted version. A user can upload as many files as he wants. Users can decrypt the documents via the server after a D date. A user may see an other user's encrypted document, but it would be a disaster if he could decrypt it before the D date!

I've read in other stack overflow post that using the same initialization vector can make chosen-plaintext attack easy. So I want to generate a different initialization vector for every uploaded file. Is it a standard secure way to add this IV to the encrypted document?

My first idea is that I encrypt it with a different AES key and simply concat it to the encrypted byte array. But I'd rather use a more standard solution for this problem.

Comment: Why are you using the same AES key?  More details about your situation and restrictions would help.

Comment: I've removed the Java part from your question. It's not required for protocol design nor is it on topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR: AES is safe against plain-text attacks.

If :

- you **do not reuse your IV**
- your **IV are random**
- you use a **correct mode** of operation (not ECB...)

Then you are safe against such attacks (you need at least these 3 conditions to be met).

On a side note, IV can be public, it is not a problem.

Worth reading:

- [Why is CBC with predictable IV considered insecure against chosen-plaintext attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/why-is-cbc-with-predictable-iv-considered-insecure-against-chosen-plaintext-atta?rq=1)
- [Why is AES resistant to known-plaintext attacks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks)
- [What is the difference between known-plaintext attack and chosen-plaintext attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/what-is-the-difference-between-known-plaintext-attack-and-chosen-plaintext-attac?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at pretty much any of the many file encryption tools they are usually a hybrid system such as:

1. Generate a new random key, $k$.
2. Encrypt $k$ using some public key $p$: $w = Asymm_p(k)$
3. Encrypt the message, $m$, using $k$ and a symmetric algorithm: $c = E_k(m)$.
4. Throw away $k$ and $m$.  Publish/send $c$ and perhaps $w$ depending on the situation.

This doesn't provide much, but it should provide confidentiality.  When the date arrives the holder of the private key can decrypt $w$ and publish $k$.

Comment: Given AES security, and considering a decent IV (no reuse), IND-CPA is guaranteed. So no need to consider an asymmetric scheme such as this one. It make things more complex uselessly, thus more risk of mistakes...

Comment: @Biv This very much depends on how many encryptions and how much data is encrypted in the lifetime of his one key.  This is why I asked my comment-question.

Comment: Assuming a 256 bit key you are pretty safe. ;)

Comment: @Biv No you aren't.  The issue here is IV collision not key collision.

Comment: Then I guess you have a birthday after ... 2^64 encryptions.

Comment: Keep in mind we want far less than a 0.5 chance of such a failure, often about $\frac{1}{2^{48}}$, so we're actually talking about... something like $2^{40}$ depending on your level of concern.  It's easier and safer to implement or use a well-studied hybrid technique than talk yourself into a weak system using probabilities.