# AES and Known-plaintext attack

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptanalysis, known-plaintext-attack

Can you help me to finding some papers that shows AES is secure against known-plaintext attack?

Comment: It's rather the other way round. There are no paper that show AES is vulnerable to known-plaintext attacks.

Comment: How can I show that AES is secure against such attack in a academic paper?

Comment: Nobody has shown that AES is secure. It's just that nobody has found a way to break it.

Comment: Related: [Why is AES resistant to known-plaintext attacks?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1512/6961)