# AES: Is it safe to encrypt same cleartext with same key but with million diferent IV?

Tags: aes, symmetric

The encryption mode that I am using is CBC. Algorithm is AES and the key size is 128bit.
I will be encrypting a 36 byte string over 1.3 million times with the same key but with a random IV.

My question, as the title states, is it possible to reverse engineer the key for 1.3 million cypher texts without knowing the key nor the IV but with the knowledge that all the clear texts are the same.

From experience I know, it would not be easily possible to decrypt the first block without the right IV but how would the security of the rest of the block be impacted ?

Edit:

Situation 2: will knowing some portion of the clear text make it easier to guess the key ? Suppose the data is padded using PKCS7 specifications effectively making, lets say, the last 12 bytes of the clear text to be "0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c 0c" as the string is 36 byte long.

An easy solution would be to fill the last 12 bytes with pseudorandom data. However, I am interested in knowing the consequences of not following such an approach.

Comment: To answer your "Situation 2", modern ciphers such as AES are designed not to be vulnerable to known-plaintext attacks. Predictable padding is not an issue.

Comment: Keep in mind that CBC mode does not ensure authenticity. An attacker who can submit ciphertexts to your service may be able to manipulate those ciphertexts in such a way that your service inadvertently reveals the plaintext.

Comment: Situation 2 has been answered [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1512/5231) and on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5355/22490)

Answer (score 6):

No, for the same reason that you can't crack 1.3 million ciphertexts knowing they use the same key but different plaintext.

As long as the CSPRNG you use to get your IVs is strong, you're safe.

You are correct in that decrypting the first block without the right IV is not possible. If it were, we wouldn't be using CBC. But yeah, if he could somehow guess the *right* IV and key for a certain block, he'd be able to decrypt all the following.

For situation 2 take a look at [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1512/5231).

Comment: > somehow guess the right IV and key for a certain block
Interesting, this would make the key effectively 256 bit long.
I have edited the question and added a second part. Could you also answer that ?

Comment: **No** applies to _"is it possible to reverse engineer the key for 1.3 million cypher texts without knowing the key nor the IV but with the knowledge that all the clear texts are the same"_ in the question, not to _"Is it safe to encrypt same cleartext with same key but with million diferent IV?"_ to which the answer is **yes**.