# How hard is to figure out the ENCRYPTION key given message and clear text?

Tags: public-key

How feasible is to brute force the ENCRYPTION key if you have

- the clear-text message
- the encrypted-version of the same message
- you know that Rijandel is the encryption algorithm
- you know that the salt is 2 bytes long

Answer (score 4):

The attack you describe is called a "known-plaintext attack". It was commonly used to break older encryption schemes, most notably Enigma in the second world war.

AES/Rijndael is not susceptible to known-plaintext attacks.

Further reading:

[Wikipedia: Known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack)

[Why is AES resistant to known-plaintext attacks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks)

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer, but i don't want to break the decryption key! i want to break the encryption! this might seem contradictory but i just need to send encrypted info...

Comment: @Leonardo Rijndael (including AES) is a [symmetric cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm), the decryption and encryption key are (***must be***) exactly the same. Also, there's no such thing as a "salt" in symmetric cryptography; the closest thing is an "IV" ("Initialization Vector") or "nonce" (**n**umber used **once**) and it wouldn't be two bytes long. Salts are used in key-derivation functions (which take a password or other secret, and turn it into a key), though.