# Are there Guaranteed Proof-of-work Systems?

Tags: proof-of-work

[Proof-of-Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) systems such as [hashcash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash), it seems to me, do not actually *prove* that a certain amount of work has been performed. For example, in the case of *hashcan*, could not the first random hash choice just *get lucky*? Thus almost no actual "work" was performed?

My question is on the existence (and practicality) of methods that guarantee, within a probability, that a given *minimum* amount of "work" has been performed *in each and every case*, without compromising the *average* or *maximum* amounts.

On hashcash then, the probability of failing to prove work is the chance of "getting lucky". So, with a 20 bit zero hash target, that's around a few in a million (the first few random attempts out of a 2^20 space). Therefore a few in a million hashcans won't really be doing any work. But if i wanted to reduce this proof-of-work fail to a lower probability, simply increasing the zero bit space does not work, since it also *drastically* increases the average work.

To compare this to, say, the workload of compressing a file (eg zip). That's a much more controllable amount of work, roughly proportional to the input length.

Say we manufacture an unpredictable text generator, fed into zip, fed into a hash function. The proof of work is the generator *seed* and the final hash *value*. the generator output length controls the amount of work and saying you could "guess" the final hash is virtually impossible (compared to say 1:2^20).

But this example is not practical because it is symmetric, requiring the **same** work to be performed for verification.

so, are there any guaranteed (within probability) asymmetric proof-of-work systems?

Comment: No cryptographic solution can protect you against an adversary making a lucky guess, you can merely make it "highly improbable". For example: I could get lucky guessing a private key of an Bitcoin address which has a positive balance, but my chances are roughly $1$ to $2^{256}-1$ (ignoring the birthday problem et al)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a challenge consisting of multiple subtasks.

For example, provide a unique random string of characters $R$ and ask for $n$ distinct strings that have $R$ as a prefix and whose SHA256 sum ends in $z$ zeros.

In a single hash calculation, the probability of a lucky guess is $2^{-4z}$, so the probability of multiple lucky guesses in one challenge is going to be very small if $z = 10$.

The number of SHA256 calculations needed to pass the challenge is of the order of $n \times 2^{4z}$, but only $n$ hash calculations are needed to check the results (plus a little extra to check that no two strings are the same).

Comment: Isn't the probability of generating a specific n*B-bit string, equal to that of generating n specific B-bit strings? With that in mind, I don't think this changes anything other than requiring more calculations to verify the answers.

Comment: @squeamish. thanks for your answer. I think this is the right direction. Im currently working on a version of poncho's answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18795/solution-with-high-decryption-cost-and-low-encryption-cost).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, because if the solution is efficiently verifiable, it's always possible (even though it happens with negligible probability) to guess it and verify that it works efficiently