# Is it true the longer the key length is the more secure the encryption?

Tags: tls

Then why don't we use xxxxxxx bits encryption? what stopping us from using a very lengthy key?
I am referring to the encryption we use with SSL

Comment: To TL;DR the answers you've received so far: increasing key lengths is increasingly pointless, as this defends an otherwise-secure cipher against brute force attacks. But typical key lengths are currently such that brute force attacks are outside the realm of physical possibility. What's important is building ciphers that are more resistant to *other* kinds of attacks like differential cryptanalysis, timing attacks, etc. Key lengths are already essentially the strongest component of modern cryptography.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that doesn't sit well with many users of cryptography. They finally found something that they understand well (bigger key size, more security) and I have to explain that as long as the key is hiding in plain sight... On SO as well, SHA-512 for key derivation from a password, and AES-256 in ECB mode for a transport protocol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it true the longer the key length is the more secure the encryption?

No. Key length *does* put an upper bound on security, because it determines the complexity of brute force iteration of the key space or factoring, discrete log, etc. for some asymmetric algorithms. However, once you have a [long enough](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year) key to make brute force attacks impossible, there is no benefit to a longer key *alone*, you must have a stronger algorithm in general (e.g. more rounds, larger state or block size) to benefit.

For some asymmetric systems, like RSA, it may seem that you can just increase the numbers and call it a day. However, RSA security rests on the encryption and signature algorithms which probably use symmetric encryption and hash functions that have a constant security, limiting that of the whole algorithm.

As a practical example, RC4 allows up to 2048-bit keys but has biases in the initial keystream no matter which size you use. Meanwhile, many ciphers with 128-bit keys are thought to be secure, like AES-128 or HC-128.

> what stopping us from using a very lengthy key?

Diminishing returns, performance costs and increasing complexity.

The effect of key length on performance is most readily apparent in something like RSA, where modular exponentiation takes about $O(n^{k})$ time for $n$-bit numbers ($k > 2$ depends on the algorithm). Longer keys usually mean longer key schedules, which may be more difficult to analyze, require more constants and code, etc. adding to complexity.

Comment: I am not sure about the statement about RSA. I don't think there is a *practical* limit to the amount of padding that can be used for RSA. The statement about the hash on the other hand is fine of course. With regards to the first paragraph, block size / internal state could be mentioned as well.

Comment: @owlstead, yeah, current padding algorithms allow arbitrary key length. I've edited out that part and clarified.

Comment: Surely the difficulty of a brute force is an _upper_ bound on security? That is, no (non-infotheoretically secure) cipher can be _harder_ to crack than testing all possible keys, but it can quite possibly be _easier_ to crack.

Comment: @cpas, yeah, wires crossed there. Will fix, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Like all things in life, there are tradeoffs to be balanced. SSL can use RSA keys, right? So why not generate 2 billion bit RSA keys? Well, the efficiency of RSA goes down significantly as more bits are added. With too large of keys, RSA would be impractical to use in real life.

Another answer to your question is that 5000-bit AES does not exist. We are definitely limited by existing ciphers. Even if we weren't limited by existing ciphers and computational efficiency was a non-issue, there are still reasons to not go with forever increasingly large keys. One is that keys have to be exchanged, so bandwidth could be a limitation. Could you imagine if SSL used 30 gigabyte keys? No one would use it.

Comment: Longer keys mean also longer minimum sizes of the actual data: You can't encrypt "half a block". E.g. if the blocksize is 1 MB, encrypted message with a single bit of information would be 1 MB. And it applies to both symmetric and asymmetric encryption schemes (and hash functions, and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

Not in general, no. For example, under [certain kinds of attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related-key_attack) AES-256 is actually easier to break than AES-128. There are many, many factors that can affect the security of an encryption scheme; key length is only one of them.

Comment: I do not think that _"under certain kinds of attacks AES-256 is actually easier to break than AES-128"_: the increase in key size gives much _more_ security, thus not $2^{128}$ times more.