# How can I study the math behind cryptography?

Tags: encryption

I am a junior in high school and I am currently studying algebra 2. Where can I go to learn about the mathematics behind cryptography? I have a very basic knowledge of cryptography, but I am really interested in things like, why is a 2^256 bit cipher so secure? I would really like to learn about things like that so I can learn to make my own and analyze other ciphers.

Are there any good books or websites where I could learn about cryptography from a mathematical perspective?

Comment: For your 256 bit cipher question, see [How much would it cost in U.S. dollars to brute force a 256 bit key in a year?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from my own experience, Nigel Smart's book *[Cryptography: An introduction](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~waa/414-F11/IntroToCrypto.pdf)* is a good place to start. I would say that you can read and understand it without any prior knowledge of cryptography at all. It is also free.

Comment: Thanks that book is great! It may be a little too complicated for my knowledge of mathematics, do you have anything simpler in mind?

Comment: This one is even more basic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Book but it is not covering much of the math

Comment: *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory* by Joe Silverman is a superb book for a college student.  Parts of the book are freely available at http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frint.html