# Why is 128-bit considered "medium term" security?

Tags: brute-force-attack, post-quantum-cryptography

Why is 128-bit encryption considered good enough for medium term security only?  How is expected to be eventually broken?  Quantum computing or brute force attack?

Comment: Can you reference where you saw this? Was it talking about block ciphers, hash functions, something else?

Comment: Likely suite B or discussion informed by suite B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is 128-bit encryption considered good enough for medium term
>   security only?

Because in the long term it is expected that mankind will be able to carry out $2^{128}$ operations because [it's not physically as impossible as $2^{256}$ operations.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1160/23623)

> Quantum computing or brute force attack?

Assuming quantum computers work at a speed comparable to classical computers nowadays, they can break 128-bit encryption using $2^{64}$ operations ([Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover's_algorithm)) which is considered feasible in the long-term, of course this should be considered *additional* to classical brute-force which may also be feasible at some point.