# Is AES256 the most secure encryption algorithm available at the moment?

Tags: quantum-cryptography, algorithm-design

I have had to edit this question because it was too broad (sorry didn't realise that was not allowed...), so, lets go with:

Is AES256 the most secure encryption algorithm available at the moment? If not what would be a more suitable alternative?

It would be great to see a comparison table for various encryption algorithms if one exists. If the benefits are comparable.

Not sure why I'm being down voted so bad, thought I asked a reasonable question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is a good start, there's different problems solved by different algorithms. These are considered secure enough, the brute forcing of large enough keys becomes [impracticable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security) this answer has the whole "how strong in terms of millions of years" [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1147/6417).

For protection against quantum attacks [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/48027/8072) answer is a good overview, for example the theory right now is for symmetric encryption you just double the key size and your are good to go. Quantum computers can be a concern in the future, but the biggest number arguably factorized so far is 16 bits, until they can do the x bits used in an RSA implementation there isn't much worry.

Of course if you want the most secure you should use a key as big as the message (a one time pad), as this provides perfect secrecy in a method that is simple to implement and understand. This has been known since at least the [1940s](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~math474/shannon-secrecy49.pdf).

Comment: Surely the one time pad crushes all before it?  Mathematically proven security and quantum resistance.  Yes it's malleable, but there is not a single example of such an attack being used in real intelligence work over the last century.  Can you find one?  And it's dead simple whereas TLS/ RSA is dead hard.

Comment: Yea but if i mention OTP I will get 1 upvote from your and 5 downvotes from NSA shills.

Comment: Courage Daniel, courage :-)  But I totally agree.  I'd answer but already there are 2 close votes.

Comment: @daniel Related to your `…and 5 downvotes from NSA shills`, please see [**our related Meta Q&A**](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/has-this-forum-been-compromised-by-the-nsa-bullrun-program) if you haven’t already seen it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I didn't realise I wasn't allowed to ask a broad question.
-4 is god damn awful!
Maybe the Meta Q&A suggests why, but, I think it's probs more likely that the stackexchange mods don't like the question as it's too "broad".