# Java: SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong() vs new SecureRandom()

Tags: aes, randomness, initialization-vector, gcm

Given `SecureRandom` class is considered suitable for use in cryptography, I consider `new SecureRandom()` to be secure (funny term, isn't it?).

If `new SecureRandom()` already is secure, what would be the benefit of using `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` instead?

Is this same kind of difference as between `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random`?

I'm debating this in the following scenario, where I'm mostly concerned about making IV random (for use with AES-GCM):

```
private final SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

[...]

private byte[] getIv() {
    int ivLength = 12;
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
    return iv;
}
```

Comment: [See the footnote: Depends on the OS, in IOS they are same](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/85545/18298)

Comment: This is library call to get instance...  [SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) See [Maarten answer on so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37256739/1820553)

Comment: Re. random: No (for the old ex.NSA kernel versions.) `\dev\random` was a TRNG whilst `dev\urandom` was a PRNG.

Comment: A GCM IV doesn't need to be random. It only needs to be unique. So for this specific case, it doesn't matter. The only reason to use a random IV for GCM is if you can't remember all the IVs that have been previously used, so you instead rely on statistical uniqueness. For that, it's enough to have a statistically random value, it doesn't even need to be cryptographically random (which is a stronger property, including impredictability and independence from all other random values).

Comment: @kelalaka This is a bit of a Java mess actually. `securerandom.source=file:/dev/random`  which block(ed) of course. So if you spun up an app server, it took like five minutes to return a http request. Even a non https daft one like my site which is pretty surprising (probably cookie generation).

Comment: What @Gilles said is true, If possible use [AES-GCM-SIV](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82105/18298) to mitigate this issue...

Answer (score 2):

SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong() will ensure that a strong algorithm (securerandom.strongAlgorithms) will is used.

- It is available since [Java version 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstanceStrong--). Check your version before starting to use.
- If **no such algorithm is available** in running VM, it will throw `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.
- This failure is a better practice instead of defaulting into weak security.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. A link to this claim or code line from the source will make this answer much better. Otherwise, this is a self claim. For example one could also say, it there is no strong ( what is the meaning of strong) algorithm then it will use the default one; java.util.Random. There is need for reference and in Java case, even versions..

Comment: Thank your for your feedback kelalaka, I've added a bit more clarifications, as you suggested.

Comment: Is there a list of strongAlgorithms?

Comment: @kelalaka 'Strong' is a common term used by cryptographers, agencies and totalitarian governments to label an encryption can can't be defeated in real time. There's a list [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62515/23115). I don't know if AES should be added as there is no mathematical evidence that it's still secure.

Comment: @PaulUszak  I'm talking about in the context of the Java Security and specially on the random number generatos.