# Questions about Blake2x: Its state size (internal state) and its security when generating keys with size more than 256/512bits

Tags: random-number-generator, key-size, key-generation, blake2

I read the Blake2x paper: https://www.blake2.net/blake2x.pdf

It says Blake2x can be used to build a "DRBG" (CSPRNG): https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/deterministic_random_bit_generator

*"An algorithm that produces a sequence of bits that are uniquely determined from an initial value called a seed. The output of the DRBG “appears” to be random, i.e., the output is statistically indistinguishable from random values. A cryptographic DRBG has the additional property that the output is unpredictable, given that the seed is not known. A DRBG is sometimes also called a Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG) or a deterministic random number generator."*

===

I want to know if the initial state (state size) of Blake2x is "enlarged" when hashing, because I didn't understand this notation:

[image]

Despite the internal state of Blake be 256/512 bits, can Blake2x be used to build a stream cipher (CSPRNG/DRBG) with security more than 256/512 bits given a seed with a larger size?

If I have a source full of entropy (like a high resolution photo) and I hash with Blake2x to a key of 8192 bits per example, will I get a key material with this size?

Can some Blake2 enthusiast answer my questions? (I tried to contact one of Blake2x authors, Jean-Philippe Aumasson, but I gave no response).

Comment: Why do you care about "more than 256 bit security"?  Does your attack model include adversaries that can harness the entire output of the sun to attack your cipher?

Comment: are you considering this key size for the PQ-PKC?

Comment: @poncho I want to keep my secrets forever, I hold material about secret societies.

Comment: @kelalaka I want to write a disk encryption program that will use keys sizes like this.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1145/18298

Comment: @kelalaka /\ I already read this topic, but I'm paranoid and I want my secrets safe forever.

Comment: So, how are you going to protect the key?  You can't hope to memorize it, and if you store it anywhere, someone could steal it...

Comment: I store the key in a microSD card and hide, if I die, other person who I asked will destroy it.